# aes_decrypt returns weird chars at the beginning of the decrypted value

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, encryption

i have 2 methods, one that encrypts data and the other that decrypts data, everything works fine in backend but if i try to decrypt data directly in mysql i receive weird characters at the beginning of the result
The methods:

```
public CustomAttributeConverter(@Value("${database.privateKey}") String privateKey) throws Exception {
    encryptionKey = privateKey.getBytes();
    CustomAttributeConverter.setPrivateKey(privateKey);
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey, AES);
    encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
    encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
    decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
}

@Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object attribute) {
        if (attribute != null) {
            try {
                return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptCipher.doFinal(SerializationUtils.serialize(attribute)));
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        } else return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        if (hasText(dbData)) {
            try {

                return SerializationUtils.deserialize(decryptCipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(dbData)));
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
            }
        } else return null;

    }
```

For example if i run this query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CAST(AES_DECRYPT(FROM_BASE64(amount), 'keyValue')  AS char) using utf8) from table1;
```

I get something like this:

```
'??\0t\0!test@itsmartsystems.eu'
```

why do i get at the beginning this part: '??\0t\0!? is it something wrong with the encryption?

Comment: The posted code does not show how the cipher objects are instantiated and initialised. Possibly CBC is used. A corrupted beginning could then be a wrong IV in the SQL statement ( perhaps also the mode has to be specified), see [`AES_DECRYPT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-decrypt). You have to experiment a little.

Comment: i've added the method which initializes the cipher

Comment: i've seen that it uses ecb mode, i don't have any IV

Comment: Yes, the code uses ECB mode, which does not apply an IV, so a wrong IV cannot be the cause. Because of the failed decryption, the content of `amount` should not be the same as what is written to the DB with `convertToDatabaseColumn()`. Perhaps the difference allows further conclusions.